# How to add submenu to kendo ui context menu dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added Kendo ui context menu to my page by appending UL to body.and added some of the item in context menu as given below .
I want to add submenu to "Sibling".My submenu item have "text" and "URL"(eg.NavigateText & www.xyz.com) which are generating dynamically

I have tried insertAfter and append but its adding it to main context menu list.

how can i add it to submenu. 
Thanks in advance.

```
var contextMenu = $("#context-menu").data("kendoContextMenu");
if (typeof (contextMenu != undefined) || typeof (contextMenu != '')) {
    contextMenu.append(
        [{
           text: "<span class='k-icon k-i-refresh'></span><b>  Refresh</b>",
           encoded: false
       },
      {
            text: "<span class='k-icon k-i-bookmark'></span><b>  My BookMarks</b>",
            encoded: false
        },
        {
            text: "<span class='k-icon k-i-grid-layout'></span><b>  My Preferences</b>",
            encoded: false
       },
   {
        text: "<span class='k-icon k-i-redo'></span><b>  Back</b>",
        encoded: false
       },
       {
        text: "<span class='k-Sibling'><span class='k-icon k-i-redo'></span><b>  Sibling</b></span>",
        encoded: false,
    }

        ]);
```

// getting element for Context submenu

```
var hrefUrl = _spPageContext.webServerUrl;
var elem = $('a[href="' + hrefUrl + '"]');
alert(elem[0].textContent);
var checkLast = $(elem[0]).is(':last-child');
alert(checkLast);
var parentli = $(elem[0]).parent();
//alert(parentli);
var li = $(parentli);
var sib = li.siblings();
var allLi = $(".menu-item-text");
var arr =[];
$.each(sib, function(index) {
    var ctx = $(this).find(allLi);
    alert(ctx[0].textContent);
    //alert($(ctx[0]).closest('a').attr('href'));
    var text = "<div class='dynaList'><span><a href='" + $(ctx[0]).closest('a').attr('href') + "'>" + this.textContent + "</a></span></div>";
    //$("#context-menu").append(text);
    var links = {
        "txt" : ctx[0].textContent,
        "link" : $(ctx[0]).closest('a').attr('href')
    };
```

arr.push(links); 
    });

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on their documentation: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu/methods/append

```
<div id="target">Target</div>
<ul id="context-menu"></ul>
<script>
    // initialize the ContextMenu
    $("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
        target: "#target"
    });

    // get a reference to already initialized ContextMenu widget
    var contextMenu = $("#context-menu").data("kendoContextMenu");

    contextMenu.append(
        [{
            text: "Item 1",
            cssClass: "myClass",                         // Add custom CSS class to the item, optional, added 2012 Q3 SP1.
            url: "https://www.telerik.com"                // Link URL if navigation is needed, optional.
        },
        {
            text: "<b>Item 2</b>",
            encoded: false,                              // Allows use of HTML for item text
            content: "text"                              // content within an item
        },
        {
            text: "Item 3",
            imageUrl: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/web/toolbar/todo.png", // Item image URL, optional.
            items: [{                                    // Sub item collection
                 text: "Sub Item 1"
            },
            {
                 text: "Sub Item 2"
            }]
        },
        {
            text: "Item 4",
            spriteCssClass: "mail"                // Item image sprite CSS class, optional.
        }]
    );
</script>
<style>
.k-sprite {
        background-image: url("https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/web/toolbar/mail.png");
    }
</style>
```